# Why does this hook call return undefined when I simply change the variable name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, state

I'm running an API call via redux - in the tutorial, I am following, they use the variable name "sales" to store the data. Following along, I kept getting undefined, and after some troubleshooting, it appears that the only way for me to get any data out of this API call is to save the result in a variable named exactly "data".

```
// Correctly retrieves and logs the data
const { data, isFetching } = useGetSalesQuery();
console.log(data);

// Returns "undefined" every time
const { anythingElse, isFetching } = useGetSalesQuery();
console.log(anythingElse);
```

`data` is not defined anywhere else within this component. So what's going on here? Was Redux updated to force us to always use the name "data"? This is doing my head in.

Comment: [MDN Object destructuring - Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Answer (score 4):

`useGetSalesQuery` returns an object that has `data` and `isFetching`. Attempting to access an arbitrary field from that object will get you `undefined`. What's going on in this component is that you are defining a variable `data` and assign it the value from the field `data` that is returned from `useGetSalesQuery`

See javascript's [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you. It turns out I'm an idiot and the tutorial I'm following actually used { data: sales, isFetching } to assign the data to the "sales" variable.